# Как увеличить размер чекбокса и радиокнопки

Tags: html, css

Как увеличить размер чекбокса и радиокнопки на css? Первое что приходит а ум это width и height, но они не работают. Нужно увеличить размер самой кликабельной части, т.е. кружочек у радио и квадратик у чекбокса.

Comment: иногда zoom прокатит, а так - рисуйте с пом-ю :before/:after или label. еще вот http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/form_controls/checkboxes/

Answer (score 6):

Если хотите увеличить без изменения стилизации, достаточно задать такую трансформацию:

```css
#qwe {
  transform:scale(1.3);
  opacity:0.9;
  cursor:pointer;
  }
```

```html
По дефолту:
<br/>
<input type="radio" />
<input type="radio" />
<input type="radio" />
<input type="radio" />
<br/><br/>
Увеличенные:
<br/>
<input type="radio" id="qwe" />
<input type="radio" id="qwe" />
<input type="radio" id="qwe" />
<input type="radio" id="qwe" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите http://dimox.name/styling-input-checkboxes-using-jquery-css/
Создайте спрайт кнопок какие Вам нужны. 
или же

```
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="cc" />
<label for="c1"><span></span>Check Box 1</label>

input[type="checkbox"] {display:none;}
input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
     display:inline-block;
     width:19px;/*Размер вашей кнопки или чекбокса*/
     height:19px;
     margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
     vertical-align:middle;
     background:url(ВАШ СПРАЙТ КНОПОК) left top no-repeat;
     cursor:pointer;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
     background:url(ВАШ СПРАЙТ КНОПОК) -19px top no-repeat;
}
```

Это пример когда спрайт горизонтальный.

Comment: тока зачем label for ? когда можно делать `<label><input/><span/></label>`

Comment: Согласен - это необязательно.

Answer (score -2):

Попробуйте использовать css:

```
zoom: 0.5;
```